# How to set criteria range from date in multiple cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have something like this:

[image: Snapshot]

I need to sum up all values for user, if date is is some range.

If there is no need to check dates, then I can use this formula in excel:

```
=SUMIFS(ValuesColumn;UsersColumn;User)
```

But how is it posible to read date criteria too? Something like this?

```
=SUMIFS(ValuesColumn;UsersColumn;User;DATE(YearColumn;MonthColumn;DayColumn);">="&StartDate)
```

Comment: Your code looks correct (except for the semicolons instead of commas). What result does this give you?

Comment: Excel drop a error "We found a problem with this formula. Try clicking Insert Function... "

Comment: It's likely because you're using DATE(YearColumn;MonthColumn;DayColumn). Are you able to put this on your page in another column somewhere, and use this as your criteria?

Comment: Yes, this is a solution, but this solution is ugly. But this works too.

Comment: Since you have the date broken up into separate columns, Excel does not see it as a date. Therefore, date functions likely will not work on those columns. Can you clarify "*I need to sum up all values for user, if date is is some range*".  What is "*some range*"? Now look at your SUMIFS, SUMIFS uses the following syntax `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)`. If you look at your formulas, they are not using the proper syntax.  Also, in the last formula, where does the "*&StartDate*" come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For illustration, I placed the data you have above in columns `A:E`, then created a `SUMIFS` formula to give me the sum of the values in `E` for each user and for a range in the day column. You did not clarify how or where you were going to put the formula. So I took liberty to lay it out for example purposes with headers for Start Day, End Day and each user.

The Start and End Day fields are to give the formula a range. Then the following formula is entered in the cell below `User1` in `I2`.

With [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) you must give it a range to sum if the criterion are met. So here is the formula I used.

> =SUMIFS($E$2:$E$7,$D$2:$D$7,I1,$A$2:$A$7,"2015",$B$2:$B$7,"10",$C$2:$C$7,
>   ">=" &$G$2, $C$2:$C$7, "<=" &$H$2)

Here it is in Excel.

[image]

Lets break it down starting after `(`;

- `$E$2:$E$7` gives the formula the column to sum values from if the
  criteria is met;
- `$D$2:$D$7,I1,` is the first criteria looking for a matches in the
  range to the value in `I1`;
- `$A$2:$A$7,"2015",$B$2:$B$7,"10",` is looking to match the first two
  columns to `2015` and `10`. Since there are no other variations, I
  just typed them in;
- `$C$2:$C$7, ">=" &$G$2, $C$2:$C$7, "<=" &$H$2)` looks for values in
  the range greater or equal to the value in `G2` for the beginning of
  the range and less than or equal to the value in `H2` for the end of
  the range.

In summary, the formula is looking for values to sum column `E` where `User1` is in column `D` AND `2015` in column `A` AND `10` in column `B` AND values in column `C` that are equal to or between the values in `G2` and `H2`.

I copied the formula across for the other users and it calculates those easily because of the use of absolute references for the data.

[Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)